# How do I fix my CSS so that menu stays fixed on top of a container that uses flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

So here is the code I'm working with. I first had a container with flex, and that allowed me to place predictors and taglist on the left hand side (one on top of each other, this is fixed position) and the rest to the right side of it.

Now I wanted to add a menu that would stay on top and be fixed, i.e. stays there while I scroll. But I can't seem to do that, and doing `position: fixed` on the menu puts it to the left and over the predictor/taglist section.

Here's a js fiddle of what I have.

https://jsfiddle.net/o72oj083/

Comment: Please put the code in the post, so you avoid link rot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/o72oj083/1/)**

Just add `top:0px` and give `body` a `padding-top:30px`.

Hope that helps Thanks :)